# How do I use a DisplayTemplate instead of a PartialView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, html-helper, display-templates

I have created a `SumFor` extension method on [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). The purpose is to take a property from a model and calculate the sum of all values and return it. This works, but the value is returned as a plain string. Eg:

`130.50`

I often use custom attributes on my properties such as

```
<Percentage>
Public Property Amount As Decimal
```

And

```
<Currency>
Public Property Amount As Decimal
```

Which use DisplayTemplates **Percentage.vbhtml** and **Currency.vbhtml** in *~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates*.

These render strings like:

`80%`

`$130.50`

(Although a little more complex)

This is my currency approach:

```
<Extension>
Public Function SumFor(Of TModel As IEnumerable(Of Object),
                           TProperty As ModelMetadata) _
                       (helper As HtmlHelper(Of TModel),
                        expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty))) _
                    As IHtmlString
    Dim data As ModelMetadata
    Dim viewName As String = String.Empty
    Dim sum As String

    data = expression.Compile.Invoke(Nothing)
    sum = data.GetSum(helper.ViewData.Model)

    If data.DataTypeName IsNot Nothing Then viewName = data.DataTypeName
    If data.TemplateHint IsNot Nothing Then viewName = data.TemplateHint

    Return helper.Partial(viewName, sum)
End Function
```

As you can see I'm trying to use the helper's [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method to ensure that the correct display template is used. But I get an error saying that the view cannot be found. I want to have my sum value used like a normal `DisplayFor` so that a display template is chosen, but I don't know how to use the HtmlHelper with my *sum* string.

I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way. What's the best solution here?

Comment: Why don't you just return a formatted string like `sum.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`?

Comment: I don't know what format the model needs to be in. That is determined by `<Currency>`, `<Percentage`> and their associated templates.

Comment: Aren't there only two options? If Currency => ToString("C"), else => ...

Comment: No, there are others and the code needs to be able to accommodate for any attribute and template combination.